# set environment variables with c-shell script

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I want to set some environment variables with script.
I did something like that :

```
#!/bin/csh -f

setenv A "Hello"
setenv B "World"
source BlaBla
```

The script's name is for example "my_script"

So when I run : .my_script.

There are no errors but if I try to use these environment variables in the shell like this :

```
echo $A
```

I get "A :Undefined variable."

What can I do to solve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use the variables in `BlaBla` or in the shell that runs `my_script`?

They should be available in the context of the `BlaBla` script as-written.

If you want them available in the calling shell then you need to `source my_script` instead of `/path/to/my_script` which runs `my_script` in a new shell that cannot set shell variables in the calling shell.

Comment: So there is no way to set shell variables with script ? every script have to run on a new shell ?

Comment: A process cannot change it callers environment, and every script runs in its own subshell.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin not if you `source` the script, as stated in the answer.

Comment: @David, quite true, but in that case you don't have a "caller" `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I was referring to the second sentence, "every script runs in its own subshell". I found it a bit misleading wrt the question in the first comment.
When sourced, a script runs in the current shell, so you *can* set variables with a shell script. That's how the scripts in `/etc/profile.d` set the login environment...